# Распечатать изображение по ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ф-я которая по идеи должна выводить на печать картинку:

```
function printImg(element) {
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<img src="'+element.href+'" style="width:100%">');
    win.print();
    win.close();
}

$('#printImg').click(function(){
  printImg(this);
  return false;
});
```

Но почему-то не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

https://jsfiddle.net/97nagwy1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Картинка не успевает загрузиться

Попробуйте добавить `window.print()` в `onload` картинки.

```js
function printImg(element) {
  var win = window.open('');
  win.document.write('<img src="' + element.href + '" onload="window.print();window.close()" />');
  win.focus();
}
```